# nginx - 404 not found page for permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-404, permalinks

Me and my friend have had a website (http://www.ferfereh.ir - sorry not english) for a year. We've been using a Linux Apache host with wordpress installed. Now suddenly all of our posts (which had a permalink structure = /%category%/%postname%.html) have broke and says:

### 404 Not found

nginx

Maybe our host provider has installed NginX. I don't know what Nginx exactly is but I read somewhere that it has some conflicts with the .htaccess configurations which makes our permalinks, is that right.

What should I do?

Many Thanks

Comment: [nginx](http://nginx.org/) is a web server, similar to Apache, but programmed with speed as a first priority

Comment: so does this error page mean that our host provider has changed it server from Apache to nginx?

Comment: yeb. sorry I voted to close it.

Answer (score 17):

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` solves the problem nicely. Do not forget to restart nginx!

more [info](http://wiki.nginx.org/Wordpress)

Comment: Remember to [add the site relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876462/nginx-rewrite-rule-under-a-subdirectory) if your WP install is not the site root

Comment: For my setup adding that changes the error to a 500 redirect loop.