# nginx rewrite rule under a subdirectory

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress site running nginx under a sub-direcotry.
how can i write rewrite rules in a sub-directory?
or can anyone please convert this Apache rewrite rule? I searched everywhere about nginx rewrite rules but nothing worked!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /main/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try to use this, and please don't forget to replace root path!

```
location /main/ {
   root /full/path/from/root/main/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I've set wordpress on my host in folder /main and got it's working with next settings:

```
location /main {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /main/index.php?q=$uri;
}
root /path/to/webroot;
```

Comment: thanks Sergei. but it didn't work and redirects to my domain root without pictures and css (domain.com) but WordPress site is in domain.com/main/

Comment: Could you please attach nginx.conf?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code to default.conf and restarted nginx but when i open my website, no image and css are loaded, it's just text and links redirect to the same page as domain.com/main. custom: /%postname%/

Comment: You have to add root path for your virtual host inside server directive block.

Comment: @SergeiLomakov you'd be my here too if you have ideas about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645386/how-to-install-wordpress-alongside-laravel-on-nginx-with-pretty-permalinks-seo!  I still can't figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
location ^~ /main {
    root /var/www/domain.com/html/wordpress;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /main/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

You need to change the php8.0 to your current PHP version in use and the root `/var/www/domain.com/html/wordpress` to your root directory where the subdirectory `main` comes after subdirectory `Wordpress`.